# develop of Taylor series around point $z_0 $= 2

Tags: complex-analysis

$f(z) = \frac{1}{z(z-2)^2}$ around point $z_0 =2$.
I tried with: $\frac{1}{z}$$\frac{1}{(z-2)^2}$ and $\frac{1}{(z-2)^2}$ = $(\frac{1}{z}\frac{1}{(z-2)^2})^2$ = $\frac{1}{z^2}\sum_{n=0}^{∞}(\frac{2}{z})^{2n}$. Then for $|z|< 2$ we have $\frac{1}{4z}\sum_{n=0}^{∞}(\frac{z}{2})^{2n}$.
I don't think this is ok because I have around point 2.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: First use method partial fractions to rewrite
$$f(z)=\frac{1}{z(z-2)^2}=\frac{a_1}{z}+\frac{b_1}{z-2}+\frac{b_2}{(z-2)^2}$$

Realize:

$$\frac{1}{z}=\frac{1}{2+z-2}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1+\frac{z-2}{2}}$$

And use geometric series.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f$ you have introduced has a pole in $z=2$. It thus seems that what you want is a Laurent series including the pole, i.e. you want an expansion of the form :
$$ f(z) = \sum_{n=-2}^{+\infty} a_n (z-2)^n.$$
This is easily obtained by expanding $\frac{1}{z}$ around $z=2$: 
$$\frac{1}{z}=\frac{1}{1-\frac{2-z}{2}}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{-1}{2}\right)^n (z-2)^n,$$
so that we have finally:
$$f(z)=\sum_{n=-2}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{-1}{2}\right)^{n+2} (z-2)^n.$$

Comment: And what about convergence radius?

Comment: @user335652 The convergence radius is simply 2 as you can see from looking at the ratio of two successive terms of the series.

Comment: ok, thank you very much!